# angularjs : filter array with unsaved changes by name using an input tag

Tags: javascript, arrays, angularjs

I normally filter an array using input tag like this :

```
 $scope.filtername = function (vname) {

     //repopulate the array from a copy every time input changes

     $scope.items = $scope.items_filter;

     //filter array if vname is a substring from item.name

     if (vname && vname.trim() != '') {
        $scope.items = $scope.items.filter((item) => {
          return (item.name.toLowerCase().indexOf(vname.toLowerCase()) > -1);
        })
      }
 };
```

```html
<input type="search" ng-model="namev" ng-change="filtername(namev)">
```

But since the user needs to filter the array while editing hundreds of items with unsaved changes, I'm not sure how to proceed. Should I use ng-show instead ? or is there a better vanilla javascript way?

Comment: Filtering the items that only in $scope.items and unsaved items won't come to the current $scope.items or in two binding it updated?

Comment: I don't want to discard the unsaved change to $scope.items while filtering. If you look at my code i was repopulating the array with the original untouched copy of the array (not useful in my case)

Comment: also regarding performance, I dont want to save the state of the array every time the input filter changes

Comment: I think the best way is update your items list only once the unsaved items operation completed and always updating a large list of items with here  $scope.items = $scope.items_filter; for a onchange event is not good.

Comment: filtering plays a huge part in the editing operation. there is no need to filter after the unsaved items operation completes. and about $scope.items = $scope.items_filter; do you have a better way to filter array using a search input?

Comment: Currently, you're using ES6 filter function and angularJS having it's own filter called $filter. I couldn't find a resource for the algorithm that there using for search. If this contains large set of data go for a good search algorithm. I am sorry, not much more aware about search algorithms for large set of data.

Answer (score 0):

> do you have a better way to filter array using a search input?

One approach is to create a custom filter:

```
app.filter("myFilter", function() {
    return function(inputArr,vname) {

        //repopulate the array from a copy every time input changes

        var result = inputArr.concat();

        //filter array if vname is a substring from item.name

        if (vname && vname.trim() != '') {
            result = result.filter((item) => {
              return (item.name.toLowerCase().indexOf(vname.toLowerCase()) > -1);
            });
        };

        return result;
    };
})
```

Usage:

```
<input type="text" ng-model="namev" />

<div ng-repeat="item in items | myFilter : namev">
    {{item.name}} {{item.contents}}
</div>
```

For more information, see [AngularJS Developer Guide - Creating Custom Filters](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/filter#creating-custom-filters)

---

> can you explain the purpose of `inputArr` ?

The first argument to the filter function is the array to be filtered. This way it can be used with other scope variables:

```
<div ng-repeat="item in items | myFilter : namev">
    {{item.name}} {{item.contents}}
</div>

<div ng-repeat="o in otherItems | myFilter : namev">
    {{o.name}} {{o.contents}}
</div>
```

When AngularJS pipes data to a filter, it invokes the filter function with the data as the first argument. Subsequent arguments come from expressions separated by colons (`:`).

For more information, see [AngularJS Developer Guide - Using filters in view templates](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/filter#using-filters-in-view-templates)

Comment: can you explain the purpose of inputArr ?